# how to apply a function to each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this function*,

```
x<- data.frame (
  'Ones'=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
  'Thats'=c(0,5,3,6,8,4,5,6,8,3,1,NA,4,5,6,7,4,3,4,5))


f<- function(df, n){
  df %>%
    collapse::flag(-n:n) %>%
    rowSums(na.rm = T) - 1
}

x %>%
  mutate(gap1 = f(., 1),
         gap2 = f(., 2), 
          gap3 = f(., 3),
          gap4 = f(., 4),
          gap5 = f(., 5)) %>%
  filter(Ones == 1)
```

It finds when the variable Ones is qual to 1 and  sums,
if gap1 = f(., 1), the values n-1, n and n+1 in Thats, with n being in the same row as 1,
if gap2 = f(.,2)  n-2 + n-1 + n + n+1 + n+2...
And so on.

This is the output.

```
Ones Thats gap1 gap2 gap3 gap4 gap5
1    1     0    5    8   14   22   27
2    1     4   17   29   40   48   51
3    1     1    4   16   27   38   50
```

Now I want to use this function for each group of my sample.
This is a Facsimile of my sample. The real sample has more conditions and more observation, but this is just to give you an idea.

```
dat<- data.frame (
  'sub'   = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  'trial' = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  'Thumb'=  c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0), 
  'Index'=  c(0,5,3,6,8,4,5,6,8,3,1,3,4,5,6,7,4,3,4,5,4,5,3,23,2,1,4,6,3,2,3,2,4,6,3,2,4,3,2,1))
```

I need to apply the function to all groups of my sample.

For example, in this specific case I would 4 conditions:

```
sub1/trial1, sub2/trial1, sub1/trial2, sub2/trial2
```

I tried to write the function in this way:

```
f<- function(df, n){
  df %>% group_by(trial, sub) %>%
    collapse::flag(-n:n) %>%
    rowSums(na.rm = T) - 1
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you have any advice to give me?

Please consider that the sample above is only an example... I need a general function working also with more conditions and observations.

Thank you,
Best regards

> *credits:    Kindly proposed by Donald Seinen on this site.

Comment: When you say `it doesn't work`, is there any error?  If I use your first function (`f`), do the grouping outside the function, and use `cur_data()` as input i.e. `dat %>% group_by(trial, sub) %>% mutate(gap1 = f(cur_data(), 1), gap2 = f(cur_data(), 2), gap3 = f(cur_data(), 3), gap4 = f(cur_data(), 4), gap5 = f(cur_data(), 5))`

Comment: Or may be `dat %>% group_by(trial, sub) %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% mutate(gap1 = f(.x, 1), gap2 = f(.x, 2), gap3 = f(.x, 3), gap4 = f(.x, 4), gap4 = f(.x, 5))) %>% ungroup` with the first `f`

Comment: The condition given in that: *It finds when the variable Ones is qual to 1 and sums* is not true. Because, if you had 5 consecutive 1's then f(., 1) will add 1,2,3,3,3,3,3,2,1 to  the sequence while f(., 5) will add 1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1. So Its not true that 1 will be added when `Ones == 1`.

Comment: That is because of the underlying convolution that is happening where `n` is the kernel size. To elaborate this, define a function `g <- function(x, n)
  c(na.omit(stats::filter(c(d<-numeric(n),replace(x, is.na(x), 0),d), rep(1, 2*n + 1))))`. then you will note that `g(x$Ones, 1) + g(x$Thats, 1) - 1 == f(x, 1)` where `f` is the function defined in the question. Now `stats::filter` uses convolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need `group_modify` if we are using the first function `f`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
   group_by(trial, sub) %>% 
   group_modify(~ .x %>% 
       mutate(gap1 = f(.x, 1), gap2 = f(.x, 2), 
          gap3 = f(.x, 3), gap4 = f(.x, 4), gap5 = f(.x, 5))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 40 × 9
   trial   sub Thumb Index  gap1  gap2  gap3  gap4  gap5
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     0     5     8    14    22    27
 2     1     1     0     5     8    14    22    27    32
 3     1     1     0     3    13    22    27    32    38
 4     1     1     0     6    16    26    32    38    46
 5     1     1     0     8    18    26    37    46    49
 6     1     1     1     4    17    29    40    48    49
 7     1     1     0     5    15    31    40    43    48
 8     1     1     0     6    18    26    34    40    43
 9     1     1     0     8    16    21    26    34    40
10     1     1     0     3    10    16    21    26    34
# … with 30 more rows
```

which is the same result we get on the subset of data for the first combination

```
> dat %>%
    filter(sub == 1, trial == 1) %>% 
    select(-sub, -trial) %>% 
    mutate(gap1 = f(., 1),
          gap2 = f(., 2), 
           gap3 = f(., 3),
           gap4 = f(., 4),
           gap5 = f(., 5))
   Thumb Index gap1 gap2 gap3 gap4 gap5
1      1     0    5    8   14   22   27
2      0     5    8   14   22   27   32
3      0     3   13   22   27   32   38
4      0     6   16   26   32   38   46
5      0     8   18   26   37   46   49
6      1     4   17   29   40   48   49
7      0     5   15   31   40   43   48
8      0     6   18   26   34   40   43
9      0     8   16   21   26   34   40
10     0     3   10   16   21   26   34
```